# flask-migrate to change sqlite column name

Tags: flask, database-migration

I want to do the very simple task on my flask project, change my existing sqlite column name. but unfortunately, it always gives error results.

this is my models.py

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
username = db.Column(db.String(length=30), nullable=False, unique=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(length=40))
email = db.Column(db.String(length=50),
                  nullable=False, unique=True)
kuota = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False, default=0)
license_keys = db.relationship(
    'License_Key', backref='owned_user', lazy=True)
```

I just want to change column 'kuota' to 'poin'

Here's what I've been trying to do

add naming convention metadata on db initialization and set render_as_batch as true

```
metadata = MetaData(
naming_convention={
    'pk': 'pk_%(table_name)s',
    'fk': 'fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s',
    'ix': 'ix_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s',
    'uq': 'uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s',
    'ck': 'ck_%(table_name)s_%(constraint_name)s',
}
)
    db = SQLAlchemy(app, metadata=metadata)
    
    migrate = Migrate(app, db, render_as_batch=True)
```

I got an error as below

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: _alembic_tmp_user.poin
[SQL: INSERT INTO _alembic_tmp_user (id, username, name, email) SELECT user.id, user.username, user.name, user.email
FROM user]
```

add only render_as_batch as true, without a naming convention

this is how the version control files look like:

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    with op.batch_alter_table('user', schema=None) as batch_op:
        batch_op.add_column(sa.Column('kuota', sa.Integer(), nullable=False))
        batch_op.drop_column('poin')

    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    with op.batch_alter_table('user', schema=None) as batch_op:
        batch_op.add_column(sa.Column('poin', sa.INTEGER(), nullable=False))
        batch_op.drop_column('kuota')
```

And it still gives me an error

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: _alembic_tmp_user.poin
[SQL: INSERT INTO _alembic_tmp_user (id, username, name, email) SELECT user.id, user.username, user.name, user.email
FROM user]
```

how to do this simple sqlite renaming column name task on flask?

Comment: When a migration fails the temp table gets left behind sometimes. Try `DROP TABLE _alembic_tmp_user` and try again.

Comment: Migrations with SQLite3 are tricky. https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/fixing-alter-table-errors-with-flask-migrate-and-sqlite has some advice that might help

Comment: @DaveW.Smith do you have a recommendation database to be used with Flask instead of SQLite?

Comment: It depends. PostgreSQL and MySQL work fine, but there's a higher setup and operational overhead. If you're going to be evolving a schema, though, they may be a better choice than SQLite.